# Wordpress wp_enqueue_scripts not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a theme and a child theme and I am trying to load child theme blank css files to override the parent theme files rules.

In parent theme,, there is a style.css in theme root dir and there is responsive.css in /assets/css/ directory

In child theme there is style.css and responsive.css in child root directory

the functions.php has this code in it but the only thing that works is if I apply !important to child style css rules.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/responsive.css' );
```

}

How can I get my custom files to load AFTER the them main css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the load order by declaring dependencies. Note that all handles must be unique:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so27575579_enqueue_styles' );
function so27575579_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_register_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'parent-style-resp', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
    wp_register_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style-resp' ) );
    wp_register_style( 'child-style-resp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/responsive.css', array( 'child-style' ) );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style-resp' );
}
```

Comment: I don't get it (I mean I get your answer but i don't get the problem).. My child style.css overrides parent style.css but my responsive parent.css overrides child responsive.css

Comment: My responsive.css apparently gets cued in inc/scripts.php on this line wp_enqueue_style( 'theworld-responsive', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/css/responsive.css' );

Comment: If that responsive stylesheet is enqueued separately, without any relation to the parent's style.css, you could dequeue it first.

Comment: I think I found it.. there is a misfiring logic with enqueuing the responsive in the main template,, I will dequeue it and use mine instead. Thanks for the help! Your solution works a charm when main template is logically set.